# Angular receiving a 500 error but the server is completing the action with no issue?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am calling a WebApi Method that adds to a database. This method succeeds and throws no exceptions; however angular gets a 500 error:

```
POST "MyServer" 500 (Internal Server Error)angular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:250 
(anonymous function)angular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:245 
mangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:243 
fangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:274 
(anonymous function)angular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:288 
k.$evalangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:285 
k.$digestangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:289 
k.$applyangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:390 
(anonymous function)angular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:3 
n.event.dispatchangular?v=jZUm0Uxsk4Ig_MVBcIx2KTRnLbeaXFiNS47wjLSNXC01:3 r.handle
```

All of this is internal angular code and I am not sure where / how to debug this stuff

angular service

```
this.add = function (myObject) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "api/theServer/Add/",
            data: myObject
        });
    };
```

WebApi

```
[Route("Add/"), HttpPost]
public void Add(MyObject myObject)
{
    _service.Add(waiver);
}
```

The data is saved to the database just fine, however angular is throwing an error and is not updating the page

This is returned from the server:

```
The specified policy origin 'MyServer' is invalid. It must not contain a path, query, or fragment
```

**UPDATE**

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "The specified policy origin 'MyServer' is invalid. It must not contain a path, query, or fragment.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.ValidateOrigins(IList`1 origins)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute.GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.<GetCorsPolicyAsync>d__10.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.<HandleCorsRequestAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"
```

This is the full stack returned from Postman

Comment: If you use a tool such as Postman to call the service method, do you note any error?

Comment: @dazedandconfused adding it now

Comment: @dazedandconfused I am getting the same error back from postman. The specified origin etc...

Comment: At least that eliminates angular as a variable.  You may want to edit your post and include the full request/response from Postman to improve your odds of getting a good answer here..

Comment: @dazedandconfused I already tried that, same thing

Comment: Tried what?  I'm saying edit your question above to show what Postman sent/received... there may be useful debugging info buried in there

Comment: @dazedandconfused Sorry for the delay was pulled to something else. I added the stack trace returned from Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Web browser is not permitting information to be fetched from a third-party site. The request is being sent fine, but javascript is not permitted to process the response because it is from an untrusted source.

You have several options, the most common being:

- Add a [rewrite proxy](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis) into your origin server to forward packets
  to the remote server
- Enable [CORS support](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) on your origin server
  to permit cross-domain requests

Alternatively, it might be that you have CORS enabled already, but your "MyServer" host is not in the permitted domain list.

Comment: Even when MyServer is localhost?